# How to integrate azure repo from amplify for CI/CD?

Tags: azure, aws-amplify

I currently have an application in amplify but I want to integrate the repo, but I have it in azure, I don't see the option to integrate directly with azure from amplify.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In your case, the best suggestion would be to use [multiple remotes](https://gist.github.com/rvl/c3f156e117e22a25f242) provided by GitHub. no need to worry if you are not using GitHub because the process and the commands are the same.
- As you are using 2 different environments you need to use Azure Repos and Code commit with git standard.
- Once you have done setting multiple repos, configuring CI/CD pipeline would be a better process to deploy based on your push.
- It's worth pointing out that you’ll need to properly setup and configure your CI/CD pipeline. AWS provides a number of services to support this including [AWS CodePipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/), [AWS CodeBuild](https://aws.amazon.com/codebuild/), and [AWS CodeDeploy](https://aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/).